# Modifying ViewState from Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I was supposing that accessing to viewstate from a class in a separate class library is similar to `session`, `application` and `cache` object. But I checked `HttpContext` class and I found to entry for viewstate. I'm looking for a way to organize the way I use viewstate in my web app and I want to make a class that handles these kinds of operations.

I also checked the questions tagged with the `viewstate` label in SO and I found no similar questions. Would you please telling me how can I access/reference viewstate object from a separate class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewState property belongs to the Control class, we always use the one from Page : Control.

The Page has the decoded Viewstate. You could get at the Base64 text through `HttpContext.Current.Request` but that's of little use.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference to the page via `HttpContext.CurrentHandler`, but you can't access `ViewState`, because `ViewState` is protected.

Of course using `Reflection` you can access to `ViewState`, something like:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
var viewStateProp = page?.GetType().GetProperty("ViewState",
    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var viewState = (StateBag)viewStateProp?.GetValue(page);
```